# Direct comparison test proof and contrapositive

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

In Stewart's calculus, there is a proof for the direct comparison test and I was wondering why the contrapositive wasn't used.

[image]

Although I think I get the proof, I don't know why it's necessary. Below is my reasoning:

From part (i), if $\sum a_n$ is convergent then $\sum b_n$ is convergent. So, by contrapositive, if $\sum b_n$ is not convergent, then $\sum a_n$ is not convergent --> in other words, if $\sum b_n$ is divergent, then $\sum a_n$ is divergent.

Did I assume something I shouldn't have, or did I miss some nuance?

Comment: If you're saying that the contrapositive of (i) is simply (ii), then I agree. (Well, the actual statements of (i) and (ii) aren't listed, but my guess is that I agree). Both arguments are just two lines long given what's already been written in (i), so maybe Stewart preferred this direct proof over making readers deal with the logic of contrapositives?